# Postgres11 can't start when I changed its default data directory in CenoOS

Tags: centos7, postgresql-11

I changed the postgres data directory following these steps:

```
systemctl stop postgresql-11.service

cp -r /var/lib/pgsql/11/data /home/eshel/pgsql-11/

chown -R postgres:postgres /home/eshel/pgsql-11/

chmod 700 /home/eshel/pgsql-11/

vi /usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-11.service
    Environment=PGDATA=/home/eshel/pgsql-11/data/

systemctl daemon-reload

systemctl start postgresql-11.service
```

So far, the postgres-11 is normal.
After I changed the new data_directory's postgres.conf.

```
1. vim pgsql-11/data/postgresql.conf
    data_directory = '/home/eshel/pgsql-11/data'
```

I can't start postgres-11. I don't know how to handle this.
The error follows:

```
[root@localhost 11]# systemctl start postgresql-11.service
```

```
* Job for postgresql-11.service failed because the control process exited with error code. See "systemctl status postgresql-11.service" and "journalctl -xe" for details.
[root@localhost 11]# systemctl status postgresql-11.service
● postgresql-11.service - PostgreSQL 11 database server
   * Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/postgresql-11.service; enabled; vendor preset: disabled)
   * Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Fri 2019-10-11 23:05:00 CST; 27s ago
     * Docs: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/11/static/
  * Process: 12758 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
 * Main PID: 11582 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 11 database server...
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-11.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 11 database server.
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-11.service entered failed state.
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-11.service failed.
```

[root@localhost 11]# journalctl -xe

```
* Oct 11 23:01:21 localhost.localdomain dbus[6461]: [system] Activating service name='org.freedesktop.problems' (using servicehe
* Oct 11 23:01:21 localhost.localdomain dbus[6461]: [system] Successfully activated service 'org.freedesktop.problems'
* Oct 11 23:04:51 localhost.localdomain nautilus-deskto[9318]: g_simple_action_set_enabled: assertion 'G_IS_SIMPLE_ACTION (simpl
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain polkitd[6478]: Registered Authentication Agent for unix-process:12752:1022414 (system bu
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Starting PostgreSQL 11 database server...
* -- Subject: Unit postgresql-11.service has begun start-up
* -- Defined-By: systemd
* -- Unit postgresql-11.service has begun starting up.
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain postgresql-11-check-db-dir[12758]: "/home/eshel/pgsql-11/data/" is missing or empty.
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain postgresql-11-check-db-dir[12758]: Use "/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb" to
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain postgresql-11-check-db-dir[12758]: See /usr/share/doc/postgresql11-11.4/README.rpm-dist 
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-11.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start PostgreSQL 11 database server.
* -- Subject: Unit postgresql-11.service has failed
* -- Defined-By: systemd

* -- Unit postgresql-11.service has failed.

* -- The result is failed.
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit postgresql-11.service entered failed state.
* Oct 11 23:05:00 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: postgresql-11.service failed.
```

[image: the error image]

Comment: Can you check the system and postgress specific logs and see if they offer anything as I find systemd often only tells you part of the story...

Comment: ```14 2019-10-11 22:09:04.857 CST [10221] 日志:  正在关闭
 15 2019-10-11 22:09:04.882 CST [10215] 日志:  数据库系统已关闭
 16 2019-10-11 22:23:04.164 CST [11587] 日志:  数据库上次关闭时间为 2019-10-11 22:09:04 CST
 17 2019-10-11 22:23:04.172 CST [11582] 日志:  数据库系统准备接受连接
 18 2019-10-11 22:27:44.795 CST [11582] 日志:  接收到快速 (fast) 停止请求
 19 2019-10-11 22:27:44.802 CST [11582] 日志:  中断任何激活事务
 20 2019-10-11 22:27:44.810 CST [11582] 日志:  后台工作进程 "logical replication launcher" (PID 11593) 已退出, 退
    出代码 1
 21 2019-10-11 22:27:44.810 CST [11588] 日志:  正在关闭
 22 2019-10-11 22:27:44.847 CST [11582] 日志:  数据库系统已关闭
```

Comment: This is the postgres's log. I am sorry the format is not good.

Comment: Did you do what the log says; run `/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-setup initdb` once you have set your new db path?

Comment: But, I have added a lot of databases and tables, I can't do that.

Comment: This moning, with the help of someone else, I checked the error message again. ** Process: 10839 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**
Unexpectedly, it was caused by the permission. We solved this by following:

Answer (score 1):

**Process: 10839 ExecStartPre=/usr/pgsql-11/bin/postgresql-11-check-db-dir ${PGDATA} (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)**

The postgres can't read the PGDATA direcotry.With the help of someone else, We solved this by following:

```
Before modification:
drwx------. 19 eshel eshel 4096 Oct 12 21:00 eshel
After modification:
[root@localhost eshel]# chmod 755 ../eshel/
[root@localhost eshel]# ll ../
drwxr-xr-x. 19 eshel eshel 4096 Oct 12 21:00 eshel
```

Then I start postgres11, and it's OK!

```
systemctl start postgresql-11
```